# Sufficient condition of Picard's theorem of an ode

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

By Picard's theorem, it is known the IVP
$$
y'=f(x,y),\quad y(x_0)=y_0
$$
has a unique solution (which is also stable) in some interval $[x_0-h,x_0+h]$ for some $h>0$, provided $f$ is continuous in $x$ and uniformly Lipchitz continuous in $y$ (by uniform we mean the Lipchitz constant is independent of $x,y$).

I am very curious to know if the above condition is also sufficient, that is if the above IVP has a unique stable solution, will the function $f$ be continuous in $x$ and uniformly Lipchitz continuous in $y$?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: if $f$ is positive, independent of $x$, and just continuous in $y$, then the solution is unique (separation of variables)

Comment: Thanks. But my question about the sufficiency of Picard's theorem.

Comment: No, there are standard counter examples like $y'=1+\sqrt{|y|}$ which is not Lipschitz everywhere but still has unique solutions.

Comment: Why not write it as an answer?